# Make Flattr re-flattr automatically every month

Tags: automation, flattr

I signed up to the [Flattr](http://flattr.com) service to support some of my favourite projects. However, it's starting to become a bit annoying because I need to log in every month to Flattr the same projects.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Flattr in such a way that it automatically Flattr the same projects every month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click a flattr button you have already clicked on, you get a dialog where you can subscribe.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Answers are expected to be precise and as detailed as possible. Adding a screen shot would be helpful also.

Comment: When you hover the mouse pointer over a button you have already clicked the orange "Flattred" button changes into a yellow "Subscribe" - click that and you'll get a popup where you can choose for how many months you want the thing to become flattred automatically. Good to know: You can cancel a subscription at any time - you do that in the dashboard.